# JPanel has not been changed due to its given x-coordinate in setBounds() method

Tags: java, swing, null-layout-manager

Though it is known that using setBounds() method with setLayout(null) is not a good practice, I have to do it for customized design. The problem is, my panel can be changed due to its y coordinate, but it cannot be set to the given x coordinate. In my given code, no matter what is the x coordinate is, the panel remain unchanged!

How can it be solved? Any help or suggestion is welcome! really it is a weird problem!

Screenshot:
[image]

**Edit in Code:**

```
public class PanelMeter extends JPanel{
    JLabel meterImage;
    javax.swing.Timer timer;
    int x;

    public PanelMeter()
    {
        this.setBounds(400,100,300, 210);
        this.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white, 3));

        addImage();
    }

    public void addImage()
    {
        try {
            BufferedImage image= ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\java\\Accelromete final\\meter.png"));
            ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(image);           
            meterImage= new JLabel(icon);
            meterImage.setBounds(10, 1, 300, 390);
            this.add(meterImage);       
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            System.out.println("Error in loading image!");
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(140, 160, 15, 15);
        g.drawLine(144, 165, 147, 80);
        g.drawLine(151, 165, 147, 80);
        g.drawString("Left", 50, 70);
        g.drawString("Right",230, 70);
    }
}
```

***Main class***

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        MainFrame frame= new MainFrame();
        PanelValue panelValue= new PanelValue();
        PanelMeter panelMeter= new PanelMeter();
        Panel3D panel3d= new Panel3D();
        frame.add(panel3d);
        frame.add(panelMeter);
        frame.add(panelValue);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

***JFrame class***

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {   
    JLabel ipLabel, portLabel;
    JTextField ipField, portField;
    JButton connectButton;

    public MainFrame()
    {
        this.setSize(800,650);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);  
        //addComponents();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you `setLayout(null)` to the Frame also?

Comment: And if you did (`setLayout(null)`) then don't, instead, have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Yes, JFrame has setLayout(null) @KDM :(

Comment: @SefatNoor: Can you show the `addImage()` method-body and the code for adding the `JPanel` onto the `JFrame`?

Comment: Full code is given @minarmahmud

Comment: One last thing too, you are going to make things really tough on yourself if you don’t like doing things the way most people do in programming, (I am guilty of this too sometimes). I don’t mean don’t think outside the box, but what I do mean is if there are already solutions to a problem, such as layouts for a GUI, don’t resist learning those solutions first, you can do pretty much anything imaginable combining Swing Layouts, if you can't then your looking at a Rapid Application Development Tool.

Comment: Just a comment too with trying to achieve certain visual effects with GUI toolkits, you will be better off asking the question how do I achieve this effect, or what is the best way to make this look like that. Instead of I am trying to make this look like that by doing it this way, I only want to know how to do it this way. Because at the end of the day it will look the same, and you’ll find that allowing the question to have flexibility will give you the best information.

Comment: If you are going to set the location of components yourself, and not use layouts, you may as well use Netbeans Mantra, WindowBuilder, or another commercial tool, to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case that your PanelMeter component is used into some parent like JFrame, you have set to the both components setLayout(null). Then setting bounds of PanelMeter have to be accepted.

Comment: If it is possible share more datails about your code, or basically explain which components are you using as layers ?

Comment: I have given all classes now for help :) @Georgi Penev

Comment: try to put  frame.repaint(); after  frame.setVisible(true); into main() method. Also you could try research about GridBagLayout which gives great options.